# Getting sp_tracegenerateevent to work in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, debugging

I'm having a hard-time debugging a stored procedure called from BizTalk.

In a prior thread, someone suggested using sp_trace_generateevent. 
[[Use SQL Debugger when stored proc called by an external process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901647/use-sql-debugger-when-stored-proc-called-by-an-external-process])

Since I need to display a variable, I came up with the following, and it works, I can see the value in SQL Profiler (with EventClass=UserConfigurable:0"

```
Declare @message nvarchar(128)
Set @message = 'Hello World 2 ' 
exec sp_trace_generateevent @event_class=82, @userinfo = @message
```

[image]

But when I put it in a "BEGIN CATCH" in the problem stored proc, I don't see anything in the profiler:

```
BEGIN CATCH 
   DECLARE @message nvarchar(128)
   SET @message = LTRIM(STR(ERROR_MESSAGE())) 
   exec sp_trace_generateevent @event_class=82, @userinfo = @message 
   SET @CatchErrors = 
            'Catch: [LTL].[CreateShipment]  - ErrorNumber: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_NUMBER()))
            + ' ErrorSeverity: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_SEVERITY()))
            + ' ErrorState: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_STATE()))
            + ' ErrorProcedure: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_PROCEDURE()))
            + ' ErrorLine: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_LINE()))
            + ' ErrorMessage: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_MESSAGE()))

END CATCH
```

So then I put a Catch within the Catch:

```
BEGIN CATCH 
   BEGIN TRY 
      DECLARE @message nvarchar(128)
      SET @message = LTRIM(STR(ERROR_MESSAGE())) 
      exec sp_trace_generateevent @event_class=82, @userinfo = @message 
   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH 
      SET @Message = 'Error in sp_trace_generateevent' 
   END CATCH 
   SET @CatchErrors = 
            'Catch: [LTL].[CreateShipment]  - ErrorNumber: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_NUMBER()))
            + ' ErrorSeverity: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_SEVERITY()))
            + ' ErrorState: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_STATE()))
            + ' ErrorProcedure: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_PROCEDURE()))
            + ' ErrorLine: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_LINE()))
            + ' ErrorMessage: '+LTRIM(STR(ERROR_MESSAGE()))


END CATCH
```

And now I can see "SET @Message = 'Error in sp_trace_generateevent' " in the profiler, but I really need to see the reason for the error.

The problem I've having cannot be reproduced when testing in SSMS, only when I call from BizTalk. My intent is to bubble the @CatchErrors (as an output parameter) back to BizTalk, but it's not working either.

Also - BizTalk is running with a user that has SQL SysAdmin (it's on my development machine).

Also same result when using master..sp_tracegeneratedevent

Based on @Jeroen's reply, I switched to this, but still getting some error caught.

```
   DECLARE @message nvarchar(128)
   BEGIN TRY 
      SET @message = Convert(nvarchar(128),SUBSTRING(ERROR_MESSAGE(),1,128))
      exec sp_trace_generateevent @event_class=82, @userinfo=@message 
   END TRY
```

Update #1: This is driving me batty.  When I test in SQL it works, but when I test from BizTalk it doesn't.  So I really want a debug feature.  I now have catch on my catches on my catches... and they are all catching and I don't know why.   Same code works fine in the divide by zero simple example. To further complicate, this is a stored proc, called by a stored proc, called by BizTalk. If I catch the error, I should be able to return it to BizTalk in the output parameter called @CatchErrors in my main and sub-stored proc.

```
BEGIN CATCH 
   DECLARE @message nvarchar(128)
   BEGIN TRY 
      SET @message = Convert(nvarchar(128),SUBSTRING(ERROR_MESSAGE(),1,128))
      exec sp_trace_generateevent @event_class=82, @userinfo=@message 
   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH 
      SET @Message = 'Error in sp_trace_generateevent' 
   END CATCH 

   BEGIN TRY 
       SET @CatchErrors = 
            'Catch: [RG].[CreateShipment]  - ErrorNumber: '+CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(35)) 
            + ' ErrorSeverity: '+CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(35))
            + ' ErrorState: '+CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(35)) 
            + ' ErrorProcedure: '+CAST(IsNull(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'') AS VARCHAR(200)) 
            + ' ErrorLine: '+CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(35)) 
            + ' ErrorMessage: '+CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS VARCHAR(4000)) 
   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH 
      BEGIN TRY 
          SET @Message = 'Error in Set @CatchErrors=' 
          SET @CatchErrors = 
                'Catch: [LTL.CreateShipmentStopLineItem]- Error: ' + CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS VARCHAR(4000)) 
      END TRY 
      BEGIN CATCH 
         SET @Message = 'Error in Set @CatchErrors2' 
      END CATCH 
   END CATCH 
END CATCH
```

Current Profiler Result: 
[image]

Update #2 - Testing in SSMS:

I'm testing in SSMS, and none of the catches have issues.  If i run this more than once it gets Violation of Primary Key in the Print statement.

```
 Declare @shipstopline LTL.TT_ShipmentStopLineItem
 DECLARE @messageID bigint
 DECLARE @CatchErrorsResult varchar(max) 
 insert into @shipstopline values ('2', '1', 'Eggs','1','2','3','1','100','1','12','1','1','1','10','20','1')

 EXEC LTL.CreateShipmentStopLineItem @MessageId = 2, @ShipmentStopID=1, @CreateBy=108004, @ShipmentStopLineItem=@shipstopline, @loopid=1, @catchErrors=@CatchErrorsResult OUT 
 select RowCreated, * from LTL.ShipmentStopLineItem order by LTL.ShipmentStopLineItem.RowCreated desc
 print @CatchErrorsResult
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that BizTalk calls the Stored Proc twice, once with FmtOnly=On and once again with FmtOnly=Off.  I was getting the invalid cast exception after the first call, so the Stored Proc was essentially not really executing.  I was mislead by the profiler because of the FmtOnly=On, thinking that it was actually executing the statements I saw there.  Thus the sp_TraceGenerateEvent doesn't actually run on the first pass with FmtOnly=On, but later when I got past the other errors, it works fine in the second pass with FmtOnly=Off.

Reference: Similar questoin I posted about why the SQL Profiler was looking different between an SSMS run and a BizTalk run of same stored proc:   [Can SQL Begin Try/Catch be lying to me (in the profiler)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930243/can-sql-begin-try-catch-be-lying-to-me-in-the-profiler)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you try this:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY   
    SELECT 1 / 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @message nvarchar(128);
    SET @message = LTRIM(STR(ERROR_MESSAGE()));
    exec sp_trace_generateevent @event_class=82, @userinfo = @message
END CATCH
```

You'll get immediate feedback on what's wrong:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 8 Error converting data type
>   nvarchar to float.

And that's because that `STR()` call you've got is not the right thing to use -- `STR` formats floating-point values, and only those. (For flexible conversion, use `FORMAT` and/or `CONCAT`, the latter of which always implicitly converts things to strings without complaining.)

Aside from that, the first parameter of the stored procedure is `@eventid`, not `@event_class` (this is normally an error, but extended stored procedures are more flexible that way -- you could call the parameter `@banana` and it will still work). Still, for clarity's sake we should use the documented name. So:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY   
    SELECT 1 / 0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @message nvarchar(128) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    EXEC sp_trace_generateevent @eventid=82, @userinfo = @message;
END CATCH
```

And in my profiler, this produces a `UserConfigurable:0` event with

> Divide by zero error encountered.

Note that if there is no `TRY / CATCH`, you should still be able to get errors even without generating your own trace event, through the `Exception` event.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, and I have updated my code, but yet I still get an unknown error.  I'm also doing a substring in case the error is over 128.  Any other ideas what it might be?  My code is working in your divide by 1 example.

Comment: Also, I tested with @userdata, which can be varbinary (8000), but don't know where I'm supposed to see that in the profiler.

Comment: Added Updated #1 - even all the "simple" catches are blowing up and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @NealWalters: Well... according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-generateevent-transact-sql), `sp_trace_generateevent` requires `ALTER TRACE` permission. I'm guessing the account that BizTalk is running under does not actually have that permission.

Comment: I did mention it had SysAdmin

Comment: Add more updates - don't understand why my catches fail when calling from BizTalk - which is where I need them, but work fine when testing in SSMS.

Comment: @NealWalters: Do your trace columns include the actual user ID? BizTalk might be impersonating an unprivileged account. I'm grasping here, but it's hard to see how execution fails otherwise.

Comment: It's running myvm\bts_host_ins; I even granted it "Alter Trace", and  restarted BizTalk Services to be sure; same.  Also any ideas why my latest catch is getting caught (nested Begin Try statements).  I'm running out of ideas on how to debug this.

Comment: Just tried logging to SSMS with the BizTalk userid... suing "Run as" since it's a Windows Service Account. Ran the Divide By Zero test and worked fine!

Comment: Going to try: Execute spWriteStringToFile 'Test-01 spWriteStringToFile', 'c:\Integrations\SQLTrace', 'Trace.txt'  from here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Comment: Similar issue, the spWriteStringToFile works fine in SSMS, but when calling from BizTalk, gives an error and I cannot see what the error is (apparently same reason I can't see other errors). The directory allows "everyone" read/write access.

Comment: I tried Debugging in Visual Studio 2013, and attaching to BizTalk Processes, but it didn't walk into the stored proc at all. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316549/how-to-debug-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-net