# Can SQL Begin Try/Catch be lying to me (in the profiler)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I'm calling a stored proc from BizTalk server and trying to debug it.

1) [Use SQL Debugger when stored proc called by an external process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901647/use-sql-debugger-when-stored-proc-called-by-an-external-process) 
2) [Getting sp_tracegenerateevent to work in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923263/getting-sp-tracegenerateevent-to-work-in-a-stored-procedure#49924010)

I've been using SQL Profiler as my only tool to know what's going on.  But now, I'm doubting if my try/catches are working correctly or not.  Code works fine when running in SSMS, but when running from BizTalk sometimes seems like try/catch is catching all the time.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE WhatItsName 
    @CatchErrors varchar(max) OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF; 

DECLARE @debugMessage varchar(max) = '' 
DECLARE @RowCreateBy VARCHAR (100) 


SET @RowCreateBy = '108004'
BEGIN TRY 
    SET @RowCreateBy = '108005'
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    SET @debugMessage = 'set @RowCreatedBy Failed - how can this be ??? ' 
END CATCH 
etc...
```

Results in Profiler: 
[image]

Based on what we see in the profiler above, is my try/catch working as expected or not?

Now, when I run the same stored proc from SSMS, things like "normal".

[image]

BizTalk runs everything under a DTC transaction. Notice the "BEGIN TRY" and "END TRY" statements show up in the second profile under SSMS (and the "BEGIN CATCH" is NOT firing - as expected), and they don't show up in the first profile above (where sproc is executed from BizTalk).

I then added "BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION" to my test script in SSMS, and same result as the other SSMS test above.

NOTE: I noticed this pattern with a more complicated issue, and wanted to simplify it in order to post here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just a guess, but probably the client (Biztalk in this case) is calling the procedure with [`SET FMTONLY ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to extract the shape of the result set, if any. When this setting in ON, **all branches are 'executed', including CATCH blocks**. The result you see is exactly what you'll get in SQL Profiler.

Comment: When BizTalk builds the schema, yes, that would be the case. But I don't think it couldn't do that at run time, because then the SQL business logic wouldn't work.

Comment: Checking - maybe it does call it twice, once with FmtOnly On and once with FmtOnly Off.  I will retest and check: http://geekswithblogs.net/SERivas/archive/2010/09/15/biztalk-wcf-sql-and-dynamic-sql.aspx

Comment: I checked the profiler, and yes it is running FmtOnly=On.  BizTalk is returning error: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. I was thinking this was from the run time, and I was trying to debug my code, but maybe the error is coming from a mismatch based on the first FmtOnly=ON call.  I will check in BizTalk forum to confirm; then come back and check answer when verified.

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, now that I got past other errors, I can see in the profiler that BizTalk is calling Stored Proc twice, once with FmtOnly=On and a second time to really execute it with FmtOnly=Off